# Simple app error on build

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am trying to create a very simple programme of just displaying a fragment but am getting an error everytime i try to build the app

Here is the error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\user2435\Android Studio\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\dx.bat --dex --num-threads=4 --output C:\Users\user2435\AndroidStudioProjects\TheSingleFragment\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug C:\Users\user2435\AndroidStudioProjects\TheSingleFragment\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug C:\Users\user2435\AndroidStudioProjects\TheSingleFragment\app\build\intermediates\dependency-cache\debug C:\Users\user2435\AndroidStudioProjects\TheSingleFragment\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\android-support-v4-0c4016dfc8794ad67faea3f8cc8fd3b23877990c.jar C:\Users\user2435\AndroidStudioProjects\TheSingleFragment\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-246e6497d26ce8d821cff4be0c3f291182761f73.jar C:\Users\user2435\AndroidStudioProjects\TheSingleFragment\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-v4-19.1.0-2cb0dcfa5e76d3d31cbc2cb35eb1e5ce1cc3a125.jar
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)

Here is the activity:

```
    package com.whosaidthat.endos.thesinglefragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, myFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And here is the fragment it should display

```
  package com.whosaidthat.endos.thesinglefragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by user2435 on 23/07/2014.
 */
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_single, container, false);
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening, i am trying to test it with my nexus 7 device.
If it helps, i have also added the support  .jar file from my sdk folder into the libs folder as i was told i need to do this to use the support files

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Build > Clean Project . 
If that doesn't work, go in to your .iml (app.iml) file in your project folder and check if there are any duplicates of the support library...for example:

```
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="support-v4-19.1.0" level="project" />
```

If there are a duplicate (or similar looking..maybe different version), delete one of the line then do a clean rebuild. 
 
If you don't see a duplicate, I don't know what the problem is from the info given.

 
Good Luck!